# Expex - defining \NNNext

Tags: linguistics, expex

In expex we can define commands such as \NNext and \LLLast in the header:

`\newcommand{\NNext}[1][]{(\anextx{#1})\xspace}`

`\newcommand{\LLLast}[1][]{(\bblastx{#1})\xspace}`

The former refers to the second following equation and the latter refers to the third previous equation.

However, we cannot define a `\NNNext` (refers to the third following equation) directly, as expex lacks the command `\aanextx`. How can we define a `\NNNext` in the header that functions with standard expex distribution files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `\aanextx` yourself:

```
\makeatletter
\def\aanextx{{\@printref{\advance\excnt by 2 \ep@rawexnoprint}}}
\makeatother
```

But remember the warning from the expex documentation:

> It is potentially dangerous to use macros like `\bblastx` or `\anextx` for reference to an
>   example because later additions or deletions in the document can throw
>   off the reference. This kind of misreference is particularly easy to
>   overlook in proofing a document. It is better to assign names to the
>   things you want to refer to and to refer to them by name, particularly
>   in a document that will undergo a lot of rewriting. If reference by
>   name is used and an intervening example is deleted or added, no
>   problem arises. If the example which is referred to is deleted, then
>   Tex will report a missing reference.

This problem gets much worse if the distance between the reference and the referenced object increases.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember to be careful. It's just sometimes I like to reference using the opposite style, and having the counterpart of \LLLast can be very helpful for the writing :)